# How to prevent Timing Problems When Using Closures?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, dispatch-queue

I'm trying to find the sum of numbers, returned from different escaping closures. The sum to be returned in main thread.

```
import Foundation

var randomTime: Int {
  return Int.random(in: 0...1000)
}

func first(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(randomTime)) {
    completion(1)
  }
}

func second(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(randomTime)) {
    completion(2)
  }
}

func third(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
  DispatchQueue(label: "anotherThread").async {
    completion(3)
  }
}

func fourth(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void) {
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(randomTime)) {
    completion(4)
}
}
```

Comment: What timing problems do you expect?  There is only one main queue, so the calls will be handled in serial order.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't even know computed properties were allowed in a global context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question clear, You want to sum numbers but their values come at different times depending on a server response or some kind of delays. If that is the case then you have to use [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Here is a helper function, It is calling your methods `first(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void)`..... `fourth(completion: @escaping (Int) -> Void)` and notify main queue only when the last value is received. I put some comments on the code to help understand. Let me know if something is not clear.

```
    func computeOutPutAfterReceivingAllValues(completion: @escaping(_ sum: Int) -> Void) {
        // Make a dispatch group which will notify main queue after making sure that all requests have been proceed.
        let computeGroup = DispatchGroup()
        var allNumbers: [Int] = []
        computeGroup.enter()
        first { (firstNumber) in
            allNumbers.append(firstNumber)
            self.second(completion: { (secondNumber) in
                allNumbers.append(secondNumber)
                self.third(completion: { (thirdNumber) in
                    allNumbers.append(thirdNumber)
                    self.fourth(completion: { (fourthNumber) in
                        allNumbers.append(fourthNumber)
                         // IMPORTANT: Leave a group after the last call.
                        computeGroup.leave()
                    })
                })
            })

        }


        // Notify Main queue and sum all your numbers
        computeGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            /// Sum all your numbers in main queue
            let sum = allNumbers.reduce(0, +)
            completion(sum)
        }
    }
```

Usage: 
You can test this in view didLoad.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        computeOutPutAfterReceivingAllValues { (sum) in
            print("Here is the sum of all numbers: \(sum)")
        }
    }

// Output on console
    Here is the sum of all numbers: 10
```